# Aquila/C++ compiling causes an undefined reference

Tags: c++, signal-processing

I am trying to compile the code below using Aquila:

```
#include "fft.h"
Aquila::SpectrumType ffm::FFT() 
{
    // WAV file.
    Aquila::WaveFile mywav("sound.wav");
    // input signal parameters
    const std::size_t SIZE = 52117000;
    const Aquila::FrequencyType sampleFreq = mywav.getSampleFrequency();
    const Aquila::FrequencyType f1 = 125, f2 = 700;

    Aquila::SineGenerator sineGenerator1 = Aquila::SineGenerator(sampleFreq);
    sineGenerator1.setAmplitude(32).setFrequency(f1).generate(SIZE);
    Aquila::SineGenerator sineGenerator2 = Aquila::SineGenerator(sampleFreq);
    sineGenerator2.setAmplitude(8).setFrequency(f2).setPhase(0.75).generate(SIZE);
    auto sum = sineGenerator1 + sineGenerator2;

    auto fft = Aquila::FftFactory::getFft(SIZE);
    Aquila::SpectrumType spectrum = fft->fft(sum.toArray());
    return spectrum;
}
```

I compile using:

```
g++ -o main.exe fft.cpp -L . -lAquila  -lOoura_fft
```

But I keep getting undefined references!

```
c:/users/omanb/scoop/apps/gcc/current/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\omanb\AppData\Local\Temp\ccMPdyPz.o:fft.cpp:(.text+0x1bf): undefined reference to `Aquila::FftFactory::getFft(unsigned long long)'
c:/users/omanb/scoop/apps/gcc/current/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\omanb\AppData\Local\Temp\ccMPdyPz.o:fft.cpp:(.text+0x236): undefined reference to `Aquila::WaveFile::~WaveFile()'
c:/users/omanb/scoop/apps/gcc/current/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\omanb\AppData\Local\Temp\ccMPdyPz.o:fft.cpp:(.text+0x2bf): undefined reference to `Aquila::WaveFile::~WaveFile()'
```

Here is the header file containing all files for Aquila.

```
#ifndef FFT_CLASS_H
#define FFT_CLASS_H
#include "../aquila/aquila/aquila.h"
#include "../aquila/aquila/global.h"
#include "../aquila/aquila/tools/TextPlot.h"
#include "../aquila/aquila/source/WaveFile.h"
#include "../aquila/aquila/source/generator/SineGenerator.h"
#include "../aquila/aquila/transform/FftFactory.h"
class ffm 
{
  public:

    Aquila::SpectrumType  FFT();
};

#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You still need to include the Aquila header file like this:

```
#include "aquila/aquila.h"
```

See an example on [Github](https://github.com/zsiciarz/aquila).

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't list my include path. But just in-case, I edited the above question to contain my header files.

Comment: Ok, sorry I was starting with the most basic possible cause. Are you sure that the headers are found under the specified paths? Are there any other warnings/errors in the compilation output?